# What does "If an otherwise " mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms, conjunctions, adverb-position

If an otherwise qualiyfying trivial benefit is made by the company to its staff ,on a recurring basis,could it be argued that the company has a contractual obligation to it and thus must do it every year?